# Можно ли получить значение выбранного option из select вставленного в документ с помощью append

Tags: jquery

Есть select, с помощью jquery по клику на один из пунктов option добавляю в документ еще один select. Делаю так.

```
     $('#select-currence').append(

           '<select class="information-select" id="information-select-
                                                         currence">' +
                '<option value="0">Выберите валюту</option>' +
                '<option value="1">€</option>' +
                '<option value="2">₽</option>' +
            '</select>' 


        );
```

Можно ли теперь так же, добавить по клику на один из option еще один select в документ? у меня не работает аналогично делая.

Тут пытался вывести значение value просто по клику на option

```
 $('#information-select-currence').on('change', function(e){
   var a = e.target.value;

   console.log(a);

});
```

Comment: Ну во первых id должен быть уникальным.А вы можете несколько раз добавить его,что не есть хорошо .Во вторых после добавления нового DOM объекта в документ надо DOM считывать заново.То Есть $(document).find('.information-select').on('change' ...

Comment: id там отличаются просто разрыв строки. div id="information-select-
                                                         currence"

Comment: Попробую пересчитать документ заново.   $(document).find('.information-select').on('change'

Comment: На ваш вопрос я ответил в принципе. $(document).find('#information-select-currence').on('change' ...Для получения добавленных объектов надо заново считывать DOM obj-> $(document)...

Comment: Спасибо за совет но что-то не работает. Наверно я делаю не так.

Comment: Уберите id и пользуйтесь классом,

Comment: Убедитесь что все id у вас уникальны

Comment: да и в место e.target.value пользуясь следующим $(this).val()

Answer (score 2):

Убедиться что `id` у вас генерируются уникальными.Я Бы посоветовал вообще их убрать и вместо использовать классы.

Для получения добавленных объектов надо заново считывать DOM obj

А в callback функции  `this` указывает на данный элемент.Пользуйтесь им.

**Привожу рабочий вариант:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='select-currence'></div>
<script>
    $('#select-currence').append(

           '<select class="information-select" id="information-select-currence">' +
                '<option value="0">Выберите валюту</option>' +
                '<option value="1">€</option>' +
                '<option value="2">₽</option>' +
            '</select>' 


        );

$(document).find('.information-select').on('change',function(){
    alert( $(this).val())
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо Ваня я завтра испытаю это дело. Сегодня уже поздновато.

Comment: Что-то не работает вот такой у меня сейчас вариант.

Comment: $(document).find('.select-curr').on('change', function(){
       
    console.log('test');
       
   });

Comment: @jaans На этот вопрос был дан ответ когда говорилось в отверте что не стоит работать с `id`.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге разобрался.

1. Получаем див блок куда динамически вставляется select выбора типа валюты.

   $('.select-currence')
2. Подключаем метод on() который отслеживает изменения change и вторым параметром передаем select

   .on('change', 'select')
3. Далее коллбэек функция в которой выполняется нужный код. Мне нужно было получать значения выбранного option пользователем. В итоге этот фрагмент выглядит так

   $('.select-currence').on('change', 'select', function(e){

   var curr = e.target.value;

   console.log(curr);

   });

Весь код

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>тест</title>
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
   </head>
<body>
  <div>  
     <select class="select-paytype">
       <option value="0">Выберите тип оплаты</option>
       <option value="1">Договорная</option>
       <option value="2">Оплата за час</option>
       <option value="3">Оплата за день</option>
       <option value="4">Оплата за месяц</option>
     </select>  
 </div>
 <div class="select-currence">    
 </div>    
 </body>
 <script>

    $('.select-paytype').on('change', function(e){      

    var paytype = e.target.value;

   if(paytype == 0 || paytype == 1){

     $('.select-currence').empty();         

    }else{

     $('.select-currence').empty(); 
     $('.select-currence').append(

           '<select class="select-curr">' +
                '<option value="0">Выберите валюту</option>' +
                '<option value="1">€</option>' +
                '<option value="2">₽</option>' +
            '</select>' 

          );
       }

     }); 

    $('.select-currence').on('change', 'select', function(e){     

      var curr = e.target.value;

      console.log(curr);

   });

   </script>
   </html>
```